# Displaying Now Playing Info from Shoutcast Stream on Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, shoutcast

I'm looking for a script that I can easily implement into my Wordpress based website that will show the 'Now Playing' information from my online radio station.

All that I am looking for is a simple text output, whereas most providers offer scripts that of a fixed size with images etc.

The stream status page is http://radio.streemlion.com:2780/status.xsl

I'm quite new to coding so please forgive my basics - I've seen some examples where you have to implement scripts and/or pages which I can't easily do within a wordpress based site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure what kind of service you are using. If it's a third party service, which is not your wordpress website, it needs to have an API, which gives the status, which you can use to show the text.

Answer (score 0):

Like its mention best approach is using API but you can use curl too to grab content. Keep in mind this is not the best solution for this since it will be slow.

Place following function in your functions.php then call that function wherever you want.

```
function current_song_name() {
    $ch = curl_init();
 
// URL for Scraping
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://radio.streemlion.com:2780/status.xsl');
 
// Return Transfer True
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($output);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$data = array();
foreach($inputs as $input):
    $data[] = $input->textContent;
endforeach;
echo 'Currently playing: '.end($data);

// Closing cURL
curl_close($ch);

}
```

**Update**

You can make the following function into shortcode like this

```
add_shortcode( 'csn', 'current_song_name' ); // where csn is our shortcode
```

Either use in your content [csn]
or in php `echo do_shortcode('[csn]');`

Read more about it - https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Is there a way I can get the results to display as part of a <div id> , this seems to be the only way the theme I am using will accept it ?

Comment: What do you mean by part of a div ? What theme you are using ? You can use js to add conent to specific element.

Comment: I'm using 'Cozipress' from Burger themes which seems to be quite choosy about what code you can enter

Comment: Since its using elementor you can just use shortcode and call it anywere.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me what shortcode to call?

Comment: I have updated the answer.